# Problem with jQuery script - Wont auto cycle images

Tags: jquery

Im using the following script:

http://chocoslider.alandawi.com.ar/index_en.html

Its perfect because its compatible with so many browser versions. However Im having problems getting the images to cycle automatically.

I've set the following:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').chocoslider({
        auto:true,
        autoPause:false,     
        speedStrip:500,  
        effect:'random',
        numberStrips:15,
        sliderDelay:6000,
        transparencytitle:1.0,
        controlNavigation:true
        });
});
```

However I cannot get the images to cycle automatically? Can anyone see why that might be?

Ive set it all up here: http://dan.ms/index2.php

Would some one take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *Choco-Slider* plug-in doesn't seem to work very well. For example, the slider on the [plug-in's homepage](http://chocoslider.alandawi.com.ar/index_en.html) doesn't cycle automatically either, even though it's initialized with `$('#slider').chocoslider();` and according to its source code, `auto` defaults to `true`.

In fact, `auto` seems to do the exact opposite of what it sounds like. As a test, I modified the plug-in-homepage's script to be `$('#slider').chocoslider({ auto: false });`, and lo and behold, it started cycling automatically.

So If I were you I'd

1. Set `auto` to `false`.
2. Set a higher `sliderDelay` than 10, since it's in milliseconds. (Your pasted snippet has 6000, but the [page you linked to](http://dan.ms/index2.php) has `sliderDelay:10`.)
3. Find a better plug-in.

Comment: Just checked out. You beat me for a matter of seconds :)